# How to capture std output by c/cpp library to QPlaintextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, cross-platform

I have qt4 GUI program with some c and c++ library for zlib and OpenSSL EVP libs. Program is working fine in Linux. The only problem is all std out is going to the terminal. I want all stdout from those library to `QPlaintextEdit`. I read about `readyReadStandardOutput()`. But I don't want to make a child process.
So guys is there any way to capture those output to QPlaintextEdit without editing those library.?
And what happen when i run this same program in windows systems ?. Since windows wont allow console output in GUI programs.

Comment: Will it be okay if *all your* std output will be put in the text edit? (I mean your whole process, not every library separated on its own.) Of course, if you don't invoke library functions concurrently (in parallel / asynchronously), you can still know which library has produced the output you're currently "receiving".

Comment: If yes, [this mail](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/public/qt-interest/2011-January/030998.html) might help you, in which the output of a C library (which doesn't use `cout` but `printf`, which makes a difference!) was explicitly requested.